# SQL queries in Spark/scala

Tags: java, sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am brand new to Spark/scala and I'm trying to import a CSV file into spark, and analyse the data within it. The CSV file has 5 columns (passengerid, flightid, from, to, date). I have successfully uploaded the csv file but when I go to perform queries on it, say to find out the total flights per month, I continually get errors - in particular 'Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: df1; line 1 pos 14'. The table is successfully uploaded because I can see it as an output, the problem lies in querying the table. Any thoughts?

My code below:

''' package GerardPRactice

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext


object trial1 extends App {

  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("trial1").
setMaster("local[2]") //set spark configuration

val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf) // make spark context
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext) // make sql context

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("Question1")
    .getOrCreate()



val df1 = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("C:/Users/Gerard/Documents/flightData.csv")
   // df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [passengerID: int, flightID: int, Departure: string, Destination: string, date: int]

    val df2 = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .load("C:/Users/Gerard/Documents/passengers.csv")

  df1.show()
  //val PassID = df1.select("passengerId")
  val totalflightJAN = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df1 WHERE date>= '2017-01-01' & date<='2017-01-31'")
  totalflightJAN.collect.foreach(println)
}'''
```

Comment: To use spark sql like that, you need to create a view from your dataframe - `df1.createOrReplaceTempView("<temp view name">)`.  Then you select from that temp view.

Comment: You have to `df1.createOrReplaceTempView(viewName = "df1")`. How did you expect the query to work if the table does not exisst, you have a **DataFrame** that is a runtime data structure, not a hive table. Did you even read the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically)?

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked. However, I am still running queries which are not registering. I.e. I run a query against (column) flightID ' 

val totalflightJAN = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df1 where to='cg'"),

 but it returns an error 'cannot resolve '`from`' given input columns: [df1.passengerId,flightId,from,to,date];'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and switch to DataFrame syntax rather than pure SQL! :)

Assuming that `df1.show` and `df1.printSchema` succeed (also, take a close look at your `date` data type), you can try the following:

```
df1.filter($"date" >= lit('2017-01-01') && $"date" <= lit('2017-01-31'))
```

you might have to wrap "date" with `to_date($"date", "yyyy/MM/dd")` (or other format)

Comment: Thanks I have used this and it has partially worked. I am wishing to use this type of syntax to find out the totals for each month. I am trying to use the count function but not sure where exactly to put this.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `.groupBy(...).count` patterns

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your original problem.